# How to remove Braces/Curly Brackets from output -Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

How to remove Braces/Curly Brackets from output

```
$t = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$t1 = $adsi.PSBase.Children |where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'}  
$t1 |select Name,Fullname
```

Name                    Fullname
----                    --------
{Anon}                 {Anon Xen1}
{Anon1}                {Anon1 Xen2}
{Anon2}                {Anon2 Xen3}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason there are curly braces in the first place is because the Name and FullName properties are collections not strings. Specifically they are [System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.propertyvaluecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects.

```
$t = [adsi]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$t1 = $t.PSBase.Children |where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'}
$t1[0]|get-member
```

Extra properties snipped

```
TypeName: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
Name                        MemberType Definition
----                        ---------- ----------
FullName                    Property   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection FullName {get;set;}
Name                        Property   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection Name {get;set;}
```

You could then create a custom object and assign the values to it similar to the previous answer but I would iterate through the collection instead of arbitrarily grabbing the first member.

```
$t = [adsi]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$t1 = $t.PSBase.Children |where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'}
$t1 | ForEach-Object{
    $temp = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "Name" = $_.Name | ForEach-Object {$_}
        "FullName" = $_.FullName | ForEach-Object {$_}
    }
    $temp
}

Name                                                        FullName
----                                                        --------
Administrator
Guest
```

If you would like to shorten it to a one liner you can use the following:

```
([adsi]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME").PSBase.Children|?{$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'}|%{$temp=""|Select Name,FullName;$temp.Name=$_.Name|%{$_};$temp.FullName=$_.FullName|%{$_};$temp}

Name                                                        FullName
----                                                        --------
Administrator
Guest
```

Comment: Grate, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
([ADSI] "WinNT://$Env:COMPUTERNAME").PSBase.Children |
  where-object { $_.schemaClassName -eq "user" } | foreach-object {
  $name = & { if ( $_.Name ) { $_.Name[0] } else { $NULL } }
  $fullName = & { if ( $_.FullName ) { $_.FullName[0] } else { $NULL } }
  new-object PSObject -property @{
    "Name" = $name
    "FullName" = $fullName
  } | select-object Name,FullName
}
```