# How to remove curly braces from string in Powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

How would I remove the {} around a string like the following? {636D9115-E54E-4673-B992-B51A8F8DDC8B}  I just want to return the following: 636D9115-E54E-4673-B992-B51A8F8DDC8B

Comment: I found this similar question : [How to remove braces from output powershell][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047408/how-to-remove-braces-curly-brackets-from-output-powershell

Answer (score 7):

Using trim :

```
"{636D9115-E54E-4673-B992-B51A8F8DDC8B}".trim('{}')
```

Using multiple replace :

```
"{636D9115-E54E-4673-B992-B51A8F8DDC8B}".Replace('{','').Replace('}','')
```

Using Replace with RegEx

```
"{636D9115-E54E-4673-B992-B51A8F8DDC8B}" -replace '\{(.*)\}','$1'
```

Using pure RegEx :

```
"{636D9115-E54E-4673-B992-B51A8F8DDC8B}" -match '\{(.*)\}'
$Matches[1]
```